# Naming conflict with keyword object

Tags: c#

So I have this simple problem that I'm struggling with. Consider this code:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public void Test(string object)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This function throws a syntax error because `object` is a keyword in C#. Is there a way to solve that? In my real code I have a framework that uses function's signature to create an API and I should really use `object` name as parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use @ before parameter name `@object` to use keyword as identifier

```
public void Test(string @object)
```

From C# Language Specification [2.4.2 Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The rules for identifiers given in this section correspond exactly to those recommended by the Unicode Standard Annex
>   31, except that underscore is allowed as an initial character (as is
>   traditional in the C programming language), Unicode escape sequences
>   are permitted in identifiers, *and the “@” character is allowed as a
>   prefix to enable keywords to be used as identifiers*.

Comment: Even if there were an error in the spec, it's not *your* error and thus no reason to down vote.  I don't see anything wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The @ symbol allows you to use reserved word. For example:

```
int @class = 15;
```

The above works, when the below wouldn't:

```
int class = 15;
```